# How do I advance the date&time by 20 days while importing a 20-day old pg_dump today?

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, pg-dump

I have taken a .sql pg_dump of a db 20 days ago. I want to import it today. Obviously the date and time for each record at least 20 days old. I want to advance those by 20 days to make them look like they are up-to-date.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: You will need to run UPDATE statements for each table that adds 20 days to every date or timestamp column.

Comment: Restore db and then do 'current_date + 20' to timestamp columns for each table